# QGIS Contour WAsP .map output file format

Tags: qgis, vector, contour

I want to create WAsP .map vector file in QGIS from a input ascii file. For this, I tried using

```
Raster->Extraction->Contour
```

and then set the option for 'Output file for Contour lines (vector)' as a WAsP .map file (here, output file name is 1.map). As output of this process, I got a output folder 1.map and inside that folder, I got contour.shp shapefile. Unfortunately, I have not got the vector output file 1.map which is required here. Please suggest me how can I generate the vector output file 1.map (WAsP file format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to get a proper output in the WAsP (Wind energy industry-standard software) format.

Since I am not able to generate WAsP .map format output in QGIS, I generated a WAsP .bna format output in QGIS.

.bna format output generated in QGIS is a vector data which can be loaded in WAsP software and can be used for further processing as same as we do for the .map format file.

So, the solution is to generate a WAsP .bna output file in QGIS (instead of WAsP .map format file).